# Программа работает в Linux и не работает в Windows, си

Tags: linux, c, windows

Думал причина в процессе компиляции, но вероятно нет.
Программа убирает красный цвет из исходного 24 битного изображения bmp.
В Linux среде файл компилируется и работает. В Windows среде компилируется, но не работает.
Язык си, компилятор MinGW, ос Winsows [Version 10.0.17134.48]

Помогите решить проблему.

Заранее благодарю всех кто уделил Время.

Лог из gdb, мне он не помог.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Лог cmd

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изменённый bmp.h

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "bmp.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    // обеспечить правильное использование
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage: ./copy infile outfile\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // запомнить имена файлов
    char* infile = argv[1];
    char* outfile = argv[2];

    // открыть входной файл
    FILE* inptr = fopen(infile, "rb");
    if (inptr == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", infile);
        return 2;
    }
    // открыть выходной файл
    FILE* outptr = fopen(outfile, "wb");
    if (outptr == NULL) {
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %s.\n", outfile);
        return 3;
    }
    // чтение файла infile типа BITMAPFILEHEADER
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;
    fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // чтение файла infile типа BITMAPINFOHEADER
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
    fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // убедитесь, что infile (вероятно) 24-разрядный несжатый BMP 4.0
    if(bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 ||
        bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0) {
        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported file format.\n");
        return 4;
    }
    // запись outfile в BITMAPFILEHEADER
    fwrite(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // запись outfile в BITMAPINFOHEADER
    fwrite(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // определение отступов для сканирования строк
    int padding =  (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

    // перебрать строки в infile
    for(int i = 0, biHeight = abs(bi.biHeight); i < biHeight; i++) {

        // итерация по пикселям в scanline
        for(int j = 0; j < bi.biWidth; j++) {

            // временное хранилище
            RGBTRIPLE triple;

            // считать RGB тройной от infile
            fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

            // Если RGB полностью красный то заменить на белый
            if(triple.rgbtRed == 0xff && triple.rgbtGreen == 0x00 && triple.rgbtBlue == 0x00) {
                triple.rgbtBlue = 0xff;
                triple.rgbtGreen = 0xff;
                triple.rgbtRed = 0xff;
            }
            // записать RGB тройной для outfile
            fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
        }
        // пропустить отступ, если он есть
        fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);

        // затем добавьте его обратно (чтобы продемонстрировать, как)
        for (int k = 0; k < padding; k++) {
            fputc(0x00, outptr);
        }
    }

    fclose(inptr);
    fclose(outptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Код bmp.h

```
#include <stdint.h>

/**
 * Common Data Types 
 *
 * The data types in this section are essentially aliases for C/C++ 
 * primitive data types.
 *
 * Adapted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230309.aspx.
 * See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h for more on stdint.h.
 */
typedef uint8_t  BYTE;
typedef uint32_t DWORD;
typedef int32_t  LONG;
typedef uint16_t WORD;

/**
 * BITMAPFILEHEADER
 *
 * The BITMAPFILEHEADER structure contains information about the type, size,
 * and layout of a file that contains a DIB [device-independent bitmap].
 *
 * Adapted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183374(VS.85).aspx.
 */
typedef struct 
{ 
    WORD   bfType; 
    DWORD  bfSize; 
    WORD   bfReserved1; 
    WORD   bfReserved2; 
    DWORD  bfOffBits; 
} __attribute__((__packed__)) 
BITMAPFILEHEADER; 

/**
 * BITMAPINFOHEADER
 *
 * The BITMAPINFOHEADER structure contains information about the 
 * dimensions and color format of a DIB [device-independent bitmap].
 *
 * Adapted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183376(VS.85).aspx.
 */
typedef struct
{
    DWORD  biSize; 
    LONG   biWidth; 
    LONG   biHeight; 
    WORD   biPlanes; 
    WORD   biBitCount; 
    DWORD  biCompression; 
    DWORD  biSizeImage; 
    LONG   biXPelsPerMeter; 
    LONG   biYPelsPerMeter; 
    DWORD  biClrUsed; 
    DWORD  biClrImportant; 
} __attribute__((__packed__))
BITMAPINFOHEADER; 

/**
 * RGBTRIPLE
 *
 * This structure describes a color consisting of relative intensities of
 * red, green, and blue.
 *
 * Adapted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922590.aspx.
 */
typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

Comment: Ну оттрассируйте под виндой.

Comment: А ваш `clue.bmp` действительно *24-разрядный несжатый BMP 4.0*? Может ваша программа как раз таки работает правильно.

Comment: ага, ведь в коде есть проверка. Может файл "испортился":)

Comment: Файл соответствует требованиям. Я даже не знаю на, что смотреть, просто не понимаю как она может не правильно работать на Винде если правильно работает на Linux.

Comment: файл-картинка одна и таже?

Comment: Картинка одна и та же. Один пакет файлов на обе машины ставил, открывал сравнивал их, даже на более маленьких изображениях так чтобы можно было по пикселям сравнить.

Comment: Поставьте вызов *fseek()* после открытия входного файла с установкой позиции на 0 от начала файла.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Mingw не срабатывает упаковка структуры (см. [#275 pack-struct option is broken](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/275/)).

Добавьте флаг при компиляции `-mno-ms-bitfields` и упаковка будет работать как ожидается.

Размер структуры `BITMAPFILEHEADER` должен равняться 14-ти байтам - можете использовать этот размер для контроля:

```
if ( sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) != 14 ) {
    printf("pragma pack failed!");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Cупер наконец то большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Есть мысль что в BMP.h переопределяються стандартные типы вин, через typedef, это влияет на размерность как раз в производимых операциях.
И как вариант, попробуйте собрать под вин без `__attribute__ __packed__`, тоже влияет на размерность.

Comment: К сожалению результат тот же. обновил в вопросе.

Comment: Тогда вариант: сделать тестовый экземпляр с BMP.h, где в хексе на бросать блок BMP файла, и провести одну из операций. Сравнить результат вывода в lnux и вин. Отсюда и начинать изменения, проблема наверняка кроется в BMP.h, под MinGw есть свои подводные камни, там не на 100% все совместимо.

Comment: @Mink, *fseek()*-то вызывать пробовали?

Comment: @0andriy, там проблема с размерами структур и типов, вывод на верификации хеадера BMP файла у автора "Unsupported file format", что говорит о несоответствии сдвигов в структуре, с учётом что файл картинки является ей :)